# How to process voice commands using ATmega or Arduino?

Tags: arduino, sensor, transistors, relay, atmega

For a project I need to start my PC using voice command. I thought to made up an voice controlled system to turn on my PC. As far as I know, when I press the turn on button-2 pin's on the motherboard get short and PC starts. I think a relay circuit may solve it, but how can I process the voice command?

Comment: Would you be looking at *any voice*, or specific command words, or full language parsing? Also, have you searched for voice recognition modules (shields) for your platform of choice?

Comment: There are some shields out there that do VR, including [multilanguage VR](http://www.tigal.com/product/2333): Are you looking for something like that, or to roll your own?

Comment: for example,when i just say "on" that it will start working.i just need this one command.

Comment: Yes, then EasyVR will do your job, in several languages. Would you like me to make this into an answer?

Comment: @user20501 - the problem is not so much detecting "on" but distinguishing it from other words/sounds which you do not intended to have that affect, especially when "on" could be spoken by people with different voices/accents, under different conditions.

Answer (score 5):

[Cornell University Final Projects:](http://people.ece.cornell.edu/land/courses/ece4760/FinalProjects/)

- [Voice Recognition Robotic Car](http://people.ece.cornell.edu/land/courses/ece4760/FinalProjects/s2006/avh8_css34/avh8_css34/index.html)
- [Voice Activated Alarm Clock](http://people.ece.cornell.edu/land/courses/ece4760/FinalProjects/s2002/sc161/index.htm)
- [Speech Recognition Jukebox](http://people.ece.cornell.edu/land/courses/ece4760/FinalProjects/s2007/mdr32_as435/mdr32_as435/mdr32_as435_Final_Report.htm)
- [Checkmate](http://people.ece.cornell.edu/land/courses/ece4760/FinalProjects/s2007/tc228_kk336_kh272/tc228_kk336_kh272/Introduction.html)
- [Voice Recognition Security System](http://people.ece.cornell.edu/land/courses/ece4760/FinalProjects/s2006/XL76_SL362/XL76%20SL362/index.html)
- [Smart Home System](http://people.ece.cornell.edu/land/courses/ece4760/FinalProjects/f2012/jw937_sz369/jw937-sz369/jw937_sz369.html)
- [Smart Voice Decoder System for Vowels](http://people.ece.cornell.edu/land/courses/ece4760/FinalProjects/s2011/wd65_yz526/wd65%20and%20yz526/index.html)

Answer (score 4):

An Arduino approach (*because the question mentions Arduino*) for achieving the result desired, i.e. an action triggered from a specific voice command:

1. Buy the [EasyVR voice recognition shield](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10963) for the Arduino, install the example sketch, and modify it to turn one of the unused (by the shield) GPIO pins high when the "on" voice command is received.

   - From prior voice control experience, it would be recommended to use a longer command word or phrase rather than a single syllable, else false positives will be too high.
   - EasyVR needs to be trained to an individual's voice, and if that individual some day has a cold or laryngitis, results may be interesting.
2. Wire up the GPIO pin being controlled in the first point, to either a transistor, a MOSFET, or some other switching device that can be operated by low current, ideally under 30 mA.

   - With a suitable choice of MOSFET, a relay may not be needed at all, to connect / disconnect the "power-on" line on the PC.
   - Relays that will operate directly off a microcontroller GPIO are expensive (certain Solid State Relays) or not common.

Ensure that the Arduino shares a **common ground with the PC**, or, if that is not an option, an optoisolator stage may be needed between the device and the PC, to avoid letting out the magic blue smoke due to mismatched grounds.